# How to start, stop and save recording from USB camera

Tags: java, camera, sony

I need to find a way to start, stop and save recording with my Java Desktop application.

I have connected Sony camera over easycap to my laptop.

Is there any way to start recording and to store video from camera to my laptop?  Or can it be done through cmd/terminal? I’ve tried ffmpeg also. Using Java and cmd/terminal I can start recording, but there is no option to stop. When I start recording with cmd/terminal, by clicking q I stop ffmpeg recording, but I cannot do that with Java. I also tried library GitHub/sarxos-webcam-capture. It works fine with web cameras.

But I need code for normal cameras like Sony to remote control it over usb from laptop.

Comment: If you launch ffmpeg as an external Process, you can simply terminate it with the [Process.destroy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#destroy()) method when you want to stop recording.

Comment: I tried with process destroy, but it stops recording and doesn't save it. Later I cannot open that video, it throws error.